# Reading list for character defects

Tags: personality

Could you recommend books/articles about character defects (e.g. envy, laziness, hate, etc.).

I am particularly interested in:

- A comprehensive list of character defects
- Description of possible causes of those defects
- Examples

The character defects should not be necessarily caused by mental illness.

An example of a book that seems to fit my criteria would be (although it is related to mental illnesses): `50 Signs of Mental Illness - A Guide to Understanding Mental Health - by James Whitney Hicks`

No limits about the date of publication (the older the better).

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. This question could be seen to be too broad as it can generate a large list. Have you tried conducting some searches on [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/)? Searching `Envy` for example comes up with a long list of books and articles.

Comment: Thank you, haven't thought about that myself. It is a good idea if you want to go deep into collecting information about a particular character flaw. It this point I am more interested in finding a comprehensive list with some description of of the causes and examples.

Answer (score 4):

The lists of "[character deficits](https://www.practicalrecovery.com/prblog/defects-character-defective-way-helping/)" can be mixtures of judgements, beliefs, attitudes and emotions. The common denominator of the things on such lists is often just that they are not acceptable for some people, but they are not all necessary bad and some of them may not need to be changed or treated.

Examples:

Laziness can be a temporary *mood,* which, if excessive, can become *a bad habit.*

Anger is an *emotion,* which can help you refuse inappropriate attitudes of others or, when not controlled by proper thinking, can result in destruction.

Hate is an intense *dislike* for something or someone and it is not necessary bad; together with anger, it can help you refuse things that are not good for you. On the other hand, hate is often completely unreasonable.

Fear can be perceived as *weakness,* but it is also a *warning emotion* that can help you avoid a danger.